# Calculate tf-idf of strings

Tags: python, scikit-learn, tf-idf

I have 2 documents `doc1.txt` and `doc2.txt`. The contents of these 2 documents are:

```
 #doc1.txt
 very good, very bad, you are great

 #doc2.txt
 very bad, good restaurent, nice place to visit
```

I want to make my corpus separated with `,` so that my final `DocumentTermMatrix` becomes:

```
      terms
 docs       very good      very bad        you are great   good restaurent   nice place to visit
 doc1       tf-idf          tf-idf         tf-idf          0                    0
 doc2       0               tf-idf         0               tf-idf             tf-idf
```

I know, how to calculate `DocumentTermMatrix` of individual words (using http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/feature_extraction.html) but don't know how to calculate `DocumentTermMatrix` of `strings` in Python.

Answer (score 5):

You can specify the `analyzer` argument of [`TfidfVectorizer`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.text.TfidfVectorizer.html) as a function which extracts the features in a customized way:

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer

docs = ['very good, very bad, you are great',
        'very bad, good restaurent, nice place to visit']

tfidf = TfidfVectorizer(analyzer=lambda d: d.split(', ')).fit(docs)
print tfidf.get_feature_names()
```

The resulting features are:

```
['good restaurent', 'nice place to visit', 'very bad', 'very good', 'you are great']
```

---

If you really cannot afford to load all the data into memory, this is a workaround:

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer

docs = ['doc1.txt', 'doc2.txt']

def extract(filename):
    with open(filename) as f:
        features = []
        for line in f:
            features += line.strip().split(', ')
        return features

tfidf = TfidfVectorizer(analyzer=extract).fit(docs)
print tfidf.get_feature_names()
```

which loads each document one at a time without holding all of them in the memory at once.

Comment: I have many documents, so I need to load my `txt` files and cannot create a list manually.

Comment: Can you load the contents of the files beforehand into a list? If not, please see the edit.

Comment: Here, it is considering each `string` in `tfidf.get_feature_names()` as single document. I want only 2 documents and 5 texts as shown in my question.

Comment: @user2481422 By "5 texts", aren't you referring to the five columns of the document-term matrix? The `get_feature_names()` function returns the "texts" corresponding to each column, i.e. the features. To get the 2 x 5 sparse matrix, simply use ``tfidf.transform(docs)``.

Comment: @user2481422 Actually, here, the two documents are used to fit transformer. Note that the `X` passed to the `fit` function is exactly `docs`, containing two documents. Just that it uses a customized way to extract features (normally it is word-by-word, but not here), resulting in that five features. I believe this is actually what you want; if not, please let me know.

Comment: I have shown my desired result in the question. I want `2 documents - doc1 and doc2` and `terms as - very good      very bad        you are great   good restaurent   nice place to visit`- as shown in my desired output.